# AppleScript Command Sendkeys?

Tags: macos, macbook-pro, mac, applescript, script

I am searching for an AppleScript command which is similar to Visual Basic Script Sendkeys command.
I want to let a programm type something at itself.

Answer (score 2):

From the AppleScript *System Events* dictionary:

> **key code** *integer* or *list of integer* : The key code(s) to be sent. May be a list.
>
> [**using** command down/‌control down/‌option down/‌shift down or list of command down/‌control down/‌option down/‌shift down] : modifiers with which the key codes are to be entered
>
> **keystroke** *text* : The keystrokes to be sent.
>
> [**using** *as above*]

Some examples illustrating their use:

```
tell application "System Events"       
    key code 124 using {shift down, command down} --> Right arrow
    key code 8 using command down --> ⌘-C
    key code {4, 14, 37, 37, 31, 47} --> H, e, l, l, o, .

    keystroke "v" using command down --> ⌘-V
    keystroke "Hello." --> H, e, l, l, o, .
end tell
```

(Note: I stylised ⌘-C and ⌘-V with their uppercase representations, but these indicate <kbd>Cmd</kbd>+<kbd>C</kbd> or <kbd>V</kbd>, respectively, *without* use of the <kbd>Shift</kbd> key.)

`keystroke` can also accept the AppleScript constants `tab`, `space` `return`, and `quote`.

The target is always the application window that has focus, so it’s important to set the focus to the desired application before issuing these commands (e.g. `tell application "Finder" to activate`).

[Here](http://eastmanreference.com/complete-list-of-applescript-key-codes/)’s a great reference for the keycodes as well as a detailed overview of these commands including more examples.